# How do I solve this exponential limit: $\lim_{x\to \infty}\cos^{x^2} (1/x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \cos^{x^2} (1/x)$$
I tried to solve it like this but I don't know what to do from this situation

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{\cos(1/x)^{x^2}}$$

Comment: Also I would like to have a hint but without differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

One may write
$$
\left(\cos \frac1x \right)^{x^2}=e^{x^2\ln \cos \frac1x}
$$ then one may observe that, as $u \to 0$, by a Taylor series expansion,
$$
\cos u=1-\frac{u^2}2+O(u^4),\qquad \ln (1-u)=-u+O(u^2),
$$ giving, by setting $u=\frac 1x$, as $x \to \infty$,

> $$
> \left(\cos \frac1x \right)^{x^2}=e^{x^2\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{2x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4} \right)\right)}=e^{-\frac12+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)} \to \frac1{\sqrt{e}}.
> $$

Comment: @Oliver Oloa Could you solve this problem without Taylor Series.I don't know how to use Taylor Series and I never learnt about it.

Comment: If one sets $u=\frac1x$, $u \to 0^+$, then one may write $$\left(\cos \frac1x \right)^{x^2}=e^{\large \frac{\ln \cos^2 u}{2u^2}}=e^{\large -\frac12 \cdot\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2}\cdot \frac{\ln(1-\sin^2 u)}{-\sin^2 u}}\to e^{\large -\frac12}$$ concluding with standard limits, as $u \to 0$: $$ \frac{\sin u}u \to 1,\qquad \frac{\ln (1+u)}u \to 1.$$Are you OK with it now?

Comment: Wait if u=1/x than where did 2u^2 and lncos^2u come from?I think there is something wrong with the substitution.Is the substitution u=1/x or 1/x=2u?

Comment: @Oliver Oloa Are you sure the substitution is correct?

Comment: Yes, the substitution is correct:)

Answer (score 0):

Set $1/x=2h$ in the exponent

to find $$\lim_{h\to0^+}(\cos2h)^{1/4h^2}=(\lim...(1-2\sin^2h)^{-1/2\sin^2h})^{-\lim\dfrac{2\sin^2h}{4h^2}}=e^{-1/2}$$

Comment: Where is the log?

Comment: Does the log have the base e?

Comment: @wolly, I've calculated the limit of the exponent of $e$

Comment: I see but did you use logs?I don't see any logarithms in here.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is better written as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\cos\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x^2}
$$
In these cases one first looks for the limit of the logarithm; the function is defined for $x>0$ (not necessarily the whole domain, this interval suffices). If the limit of the logarithm is $l$, then the sought limit is $e^l$.

We can also do the substitution $t=1/x$, so we're led to
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\log\cos\frac{1}{x}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log\cos t}{t^2}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1-\sin^2 t)}{2t^2}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{-\sin^2t+o(t^2)}{2t^2}
$$

Comment: log of what?Log of e?What's the base of the log?

Comment: In the first reply I see log of e.Is the base e?

Comment: @wolly Yes, the notation “log” for the natural logarithm is much older than the horrible “ln”, which I sternly refuse to employ.

Comment: What does 0(t^2) means?Can you solve this without O notation or Taylor series?

Comment: @wolly That's standard notation. $o(t^2)$ denotes any function such that $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{o(t^2)}{t^2}=0$. You can use l’Hôpital, if you so prefer.